# How to select with regex multiple lines with two or even more conditional groups/matches?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I need in this kind of files to search for [Documentation] and when it find then to select text in first line. If next  row starts with space then three dots and spaces select also text from all such lines.

```
@{TEST_SCREENS_WITH_TIMEOUT}    ShowDesc    ShowOsAndCountryCode    ShowSW  
...                             Checksum_PPSU   Checksum_BPSU                   
...                             Datetime_Clock  Datetime_DDMM
...                             ShowHWRevBaseboard  ShowHWRevSOM

*** Keywords ***
Program Version contain
[Documentation]     Read out program version and compare it with
    ...                 Comparison is done with "Should Contain"
    ...                 it checks if 

Tarif EPS is
[Documentation]     Read out tarif EPS and compare it with ${TARIF_EPS}
    ...                 Comparison is done with "Should be equal"
[Arguments]         ${TARIF_EPS}

Should be equal    ${disp_traf_eps}    ${TARIF_EPS}    Tarif EPS


Release Date contain
[Documentation] Read out program version and compare it with ${RELEASE_DATE}
```

This is what I manage to get till now:
    ^\s*[Documentation]\s+(.+)(?:(?=\s+...\s+(.+)))*

Entire text and regex I have tried so far can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/Jbzd4e/1

In my case it only selects 2 rows. I need to select only Documentation text!

Comment: Voted to close as "why isn't this code working."  I don't see a clear problem statement here.

Comment: `^\s*\[Documentation]\s+(.+(?:\n\s*\.\.\..+)*)` ? See https://regex101.com/r/Vbc4uH/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but you included "    ....      " so you included spaces and dots from next line which I would like to skip. I wanted only text.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to select only Documentation text! I think it is quite clear.

Comment: @idomoni There is no way to "skip" a part of a text within one match operation. You will need to replace those after  the match is found.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not even with two or more defined groups?

Comment: Thanks for "-". I think that question was fairly good and that some other users will search for similar solutions and if is really not possible at least they will read here that it is not possible to do it under one expression.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is possible, please see answer from Mark Cooper

Comment: Those are *separate* multiple matches, so what I said is true. *There is no way to "skip" a part of a text within one match operation. You will need to replace those after the match is found.*

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen could you please remove your "-1" as you can see everybody else understand it and Mark Cooper provided nice solution for it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes but that was what I needed. It is I asked is it possible with two or more groups so I meant by that two or more multiple matches. It is capturing only the text of Ducumentation and skipping spaces, dots and tag [Documentation]. Thats all. I know that you are regex expert far more better than many other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: `^\s{1,}\[Documentation]\s*(.*)$|^\s{1,}\.{3}\s*(.*)$`

https://regex101.com/r/C5FTzP/2

**Update;**

Or this might be more elegant: `^\s{1,}(\[Documentation]|\.{3})\s*(.*)$`

https://regex101.com/r/C5FTzP/4